# I need my page footer to stretch the whole page using bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, footer

I'm currently building a site using twitter bootstrap 3 as the frame work for the front end.

I'm trying to get my footer to stretch to 100% of the page the same way the navbar and carousel do, but it keeps keeping it within the page container i think.

I'd really appreciate some help as I@m a bit of a novice with bootstrap.

The page is http://dmc.dudmc.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to wrap the footer container between these:

```html
<div role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

    <!-- your footer -->

    </div>
</div>
```

You may have to further edit the classes, but by default, this should work.

**EDITED:** having another look at your code i see that the container you use for your footer is within another container. I suggest you either take it out of that container or simply apply `width:100%` to both containers (in line or in your custom css). Make sure you remove any side margins.