# Unable to stretch footer horizontally on page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am fairly new to web development and I am trying to stretch the footer section horizontally on my website so, but instead it is appearing as a box. I have repeatedly tried changing the background of every div of the code but things are not working out. As a troubleshooting step I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312119/i-need-my-page-footer-to-stretch-the-whole-page-using-bootstrap-3).I am using Bootstrap.
[image]

Here is my **HTML**:

```
    <div role="navigation" style="background-color: blue">
        <div class="container">
            <footer class="container-fluid" id="contact" style="width: 100%;">      
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h2>Contact Us</h2>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 boxes">
                                <div class="contact-box">
                                    <div class="contact-icon pull-left"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-fw"></i></div>
                                    <div class="contact-details pull-left">
                                        <a href="#">221 Baker Street</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="contact-box extra-left-padding">
                                    <div class="contact-icon pull-left"><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-fw"></i></div>
                                    <div class="contact-details pull-left">
                                        <a href="mailto:fun@funny.nl">fun@funny.nl</a><br />
                                        <a href="tel:0000-0000-0000">000-000-000</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="copyright">&copy; Hello!</span>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my **CSS:**

```
footer {
    background-color: #002776;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 14px;
}
footer h2 {
    margin: 0 0 40px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
footer div.boxes {
    text-align: center;
}
footer div.contact-box {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    width: 280px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    footer div.contact-box {
        width: 90%;
    }
}
footer div.contact-box.extra-left-padding {
    padding-left: 80px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    footer div.contact-box.extra-left-padding {
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}
footer div.contact-box div.contact-icon {
    background-color: #0038a9;
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
}
footer div.contact-box div.contact-details {
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.75em;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    footer div.contact-box div.contact-details {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
footer span.contact-link {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 70px;
}
footer a {
    color: #F0F0F0;
}
footer a:hover {
    color: #00a1de;
}
footer span.copyright {
    color: #999;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}
footer span.copyright img {
    max-width: 75px;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
}
```

Comment: In Bootstrap the `.container` class has a fixed width...

Comment: I added the div with the .container class after following the link mentioned above. If I remove the .container class div and the navigation role div, the output is still the same

Comment: `.container-fluid` has padding..so you'd have to remove that. See - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ZbQRPQ

Comment: If you set the `footer` to have `width: 100%; display: block` it will be 100% the width of its container, but it may be that the container has a less-than-100% width set on it.

Comment: I did this `<footer class="container-fluid" id="contact" style="padding: 0px;"> ` but the output was this https://gyazo.com/370f0f964c87104b925616424857e0cb

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel I did this `<footer class="container-fluid" id="contact" style="width: 100%; display: block;">` and got this https://gyazo.com/d32cb95c550a8d642b3b0f24585f803c

Comment: Also remove the `container-fluid` class, that might be effecting it. Otherwise your containing element (whatever is the parent (or parent recursively) of `footer`) has a fixed width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML code must be only : 
Css is good.

```
<footer class="container-fluid">      
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h2>Contact Us</h2>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 boxes">
                                <div class="contact-box">
                                    <div class="contact-icon pull-left"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-fw"></i></div>
                                    <div class="contact-details pull-left">
                                        <a href="#">221 Baker Street</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="contact-box extra-left-padding">
                                    <div class="contact-icon pull-left"><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-fw"></i></div>
                                    <div class="contact-details pull-left">
                                        <a href="mailto:fun@funny.nl">fun@funny.nl</a><br />
                                        <a href="tel:0000-0000-0000">000-000-000</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="copyright">&copy; Hello!</span>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </footer>
```

Comment: Hi ! Appreciate the swift response. It worked. Cheers :)